# Why my Amazon EC2 instance limit is zero by default?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I was successfully using Amazon S3 for some time. Now I was trying to start EC2 instance, but I got an error about exceeding my limit.

I went to "Limits" tab in EC2 menu and I see that all my instance limits are set to zero.

I've sent a limit increase request about 16 hours ago but got no reply.

1. Is that normal that all EC2 instance limits are set to 0 by default?
2. Is than normal that there is no reply to my request for 16 hours already?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) What sort of account do you have with AWS, and AMI role you are using? 2) If your support plan is the 'Basic' one then yes, it can take a while for them to respond, depending on priorities of tickets I suppose.

Comment: You chose a default region or two when you set up your account. Your initial limit is probably something like one or two t2.micro. They'll increase the limits, it will just take a little time. If you can't wait, run spot instances, I don't think the limits apply to them. Be aware that spot instances can be [terminated at any time](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-spot-instances-work.html) with virtually no warning so you need appropriate backups.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your questions directly.

0) Limits protect AWS infrastructure from overuse, prevent significant loss by fraud, and prevent customers from running up large bills unintentionally. [More here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html). For example, if your access keys are made public by mistake someone could spin up many p2.16xlarge instances to run crypto currency mining at $14/hr.

1) No. The region you select should allow at least one t2.micro, as per the free tier. Once you establish that you will actually pay your bill AWS will raise limits.

2) I wouldn't call 16 hours unusual. The first time I requested an increase it took 12 hours to reply and 4 days to do the increase. The second time it took a couple of hours to reply and around 36 hours to do the increase.

**Edit August 2018**

I was on an AWS training course recently. We had scripts create a number of AWS accounts. One of those accounts had a limit of zero EC2 instances in some regions, with only a single t2.micro and another t2 instance size I don't recall available. I got an email in the next 12 hours saying the limits had been increased and instances could be created. There's was a theory that the region we were using (US-East-1) had some kind of a temporary resource constraint.

So in some cases the answer is "be patient, limits will automatically increase". The default limits do increase over time, which I assume is to protect AWS against people and automated systems taking advantage of their free tier.

Comment: Addendum to 0)...*and* they protect customers from shooting themselves in the foot financially. :)